# ER Diagram/Schema Setup with Admin/Member roles

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, schema, entity-relationship

I am learning databases and am trying to create an ER Diagram for a scenario where a User (has own table) can create an Event (has own table).

A User can have many Events and an Event can have many Users so I plan to use a join table called UserEvent.

In this scenario I want a User to be able to create an Event and be the only admin for that event so that he/she can edit or delete the Event.

For which table would I want to specify the 'user role' (Admin or Member) of the Event that was created? Is this the best setup for this scenario?

Comment: Is there only one admin per event? if so event table makes the most sense.  If there can be multiple admins, then userEvent makes sense as an additional column.  the association of a user to an event in this table denotes members. so an additional role isn't needed. (just my 2 cents)

Comment: @xQbert, I only want one admin per event, have updated my question accordingly. Does your recommendation still stand for adding a column to userEvent table for 'role'?

Comment: As you'll learn about Database design it all depends on requirements.  If you know that there is always and will always be only one admin per event, then the userID on the event table makes sense as the "owner" of the event.  The userEvent table makes sense to define those who may be involved with the event.  If users have different roles within events then I'd have a role column.  However if all users are treated the same then I wouldn't bother having a role column because knowing a user is involved in the event is enough.  If you care about history and retaining it, timestamps might help too